# I can't use onClick in dynamically created views

Tags: java, android

I am dealing with this error for 2 days. Searched for lots of questions but none of them solved my problem
When I click on a dynamic view that has onClick this error shows up:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method Save(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.widget.Button with id 'save'

Even if inside the method is blank.

This is an news app and when I click add button an edit view shows up and I write the news and then I click the save button, then news is displaying on the main screen. But as I said when I tap on the save button it crashes. I is totally about onClick but I am expecting your ideas :)

***MainActivity***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView header;
    TextView summary;

    EditText editHeader;
    EditText editSummary;

    View news_edit;
    Button saveButton;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        news_edit = findViewById(R.id.news_edit);
        saveButton = findViewById(R.id.save);

        header = findViewById(R.id.header);
        summary = findViewById(R.id.summary);
        editHeader = findViewById(R.id.editHeader);
        editSummary = findViewById(R.id.editSummary);

    }
    public void Save(View view) {

        LayoutInflater vi = null;
        vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.news, null);

        ViewGroup insertPoint = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.allNews);
        insertPoint.addView(v, 0, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

    }

    public void editNews(View view) {

        LayoutInflater vi = null;
        vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.news_edit_view, null);

        ViewGroup insertPoint = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        insertPoint.addView(v, 0, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

    }
```

**news_edit_view**

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/news_edit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/grey_background"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Başlık Yazınız"></EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editSummary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_backgrounda"
        android:ems="20"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:hint="Haber içeriğini buraya yazınız. Olabildiğince anlaşılabilir, kaynak belirterek ve yazım kurallarına uyarak yazmanız önemle rica olunur."
        android:padding="7dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:onClick="Save"
        android:text="Save" />

</GridLayout>
```

Comment: `When I click on a dynamic view` What do you consider to be a 'dynamic' view? What is your dynsamic view?

Comment: In main activity you should use R.layout.news_edit_view for setContentView first. Or otherwise move your button to R.layout.activity_main.

Comment: Can you explain it more clear, I already put R.layout.news_edit_view in editNews() method.

Comment: I restored the ID Value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are setting the parent layout for your activity in this line :

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

although you are trying to retrieve Views from

```
R.layout.news_edit_view
```

That is why this line(amongst others) :

```
saveButton = findViewById(R.id.save);
```

cannot find the Button because the Button is inside the news_edit_view layout, and this is not inflated yet, and thus you cannot set an OnClickListener and it returns null.

A simple

```
<include layout="@layout/news_edit_view"/>
```

added in your activity_main.xml might solve the issue, because your news_edit_view then will be added to your activity_main.xml.

Or maybe you wanted :

```
setContentView(R.layout.news_edit_view);
```

in the first place.
Just make sure you inflate the right layout of which child Views you want to access.

Comment: Huuge thanks for explanation and solving my problem, have a great day :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

            TextView header;
            TextView summary;
        
            EditText editHeader;
            EditText editSummary;
            View news_edit;
            Button saveButton;
        
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
                news_edit = findViewById(R.id.news_edit);
                saveButton = findViewById(R.id.save);
        
                header = findViewById(R.id.header);
                summary = findViewById(R.id.summary);
                editHeader = findViewById(R.id.editHeader);
                editSummary = findViewById(R.id.editSummary);
    
                saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Save();
                 }
                });
    
    
        
            }
            public void Save() {
        
                LayoutInflater vi = null;
                vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        
                View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.news, null);
        
                ViewGroup insertPoint = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.allNews);
                insertPoint.addView(v, 0, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        
            }
    
          
    
    
        
            public void editNews(View view) {
        
                LayoutInflater vi = null;
                vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        
                View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.news_edit_view, null);
        
                ViewGroup insertPoint = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
                insertPoint.addView(v, 0, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        
            }
}
```

Layout

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/news_edit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/grey_background"
    android:padding="10dp">
    
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editHeader"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Başlık Yazınız"></EditText>
    
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editSummary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_backgrounda"
            android:ems="20"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:hint="Haber içeriğini buraya yazınız. Olabildiğince anlaşılabilir, kaynak belirterek ve yazım kurallarına uyarak yazmanız önemle rica olunur."
            android:padding="7dp" />
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/save"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:text="Save" />
    
    </GridLayout>
```

Comment: I copy pasted them but it errors on onClickListener now. App is not even opening :/

Comment: What is the mistake? I edited your source code.

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: this would require the layout to be activity_main.xml which seems like the OP is trying to access Views from news_edit_view.xml